# Added libraries to project ok but dependencies are wrong

Tags: android, eclipse, build, sdk, dependencies

Recently I've been "cleaning" the old versions from my SDK manager, but now inside my project, the added libraries are wrong... I do not know why, but inside the tab Android they are checked right (green check), but inside the tab android dependencies all of them are wrong (red check)

[image]

[image]

Any idea why? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove dependencies from project has error form build path option.
then add your library project again now clean project.

Comment: Thanks it works!! I was getting crazy with this!! Cleaning first the referenced projects and after the main project solved all!! No need to remove and add again the library projects